# I cannot move files from one folder to another with shutil.move after several attempts

Tags: python, python-2.7, shutil, del

There are many posts related with moving several files from one existing directory to another existing directory. Unfortunately, that has not worked for me yet, in Windows 8 and Python 2.7.

My best attempt seems to be with this code, because `shutil.copy` works fine, but with `shutil.move` I get

> WindowsError: [Error 32] The process cannot access the file because it
>   is being used by another process

```
import shutil
import os

path = "G:\Tables\"
dest = "G:\Tables\Soil"

for file in os.listdir(path):
    fullpath = os.path.join(path, file)
    f = open( fullpath , 'r+')
    dataname = f.name
    print dataname

    shutil.move(fullpath, dest)

del file
```

I know that the problem is that I don't close the files, but I've already tried it, both with `del file` and `close.file()`.

Another way I tried is as follows:

```
import shutil
from os.path import join

source = os.path.join("G:/", "Tables")
dest1 = os.path.join("G:/", "Tables", "Yield")
dest2 = os.path.join("G:/", "Tables", "Soil")

#alternatively
#source = r"G:/Tables/"
#dest1 = r"G:/Tables/Yield"
#dest2 = r"G:/Tables/Soil"

#or
#source = "G:\\Tables\\Millet"
#dest1 = "G:\\Tables\\Millet\\Yield"
#dest2 = "G:\\Tables\\Millet\\Soil"

files = os.listdir(source)

for f in files:
    if (f.endswith("harvest.out")):
        shutil.move(f, dest1)
    elif (f.endswith("sow.out")):
        shutil.move(f, dest2)
```

If I use os.path.join (either using "G:" or "G:/"), then I get

```
WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified:
'G:Tables\\Yield/*.*',
```

If I use forward slashes (`source = r"G:/Tables/"`), then I get

`IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Pepper_harvest.out'*`,

I just need one way to move files from one folder to another, that's all...

Comment: Did you use `file.close()` or `close.file()`?

Comment: Style tip: When you do `for file in os.listdir(path):`, `file` isn't a file, it's a string. Strings can't be closed and deleting them doesn't free up file handles in the OS. Consider renaming the variable to `filename` to avoid this confusion.

Answer (score 1):

`shutil.move` is probably looking in the current working directory for `f`, rather than the source directory. Try specifying the full path.

```
for f in files:
    if (f.endswith("harvest.out")):
        shutil.move(os.path.join(source, f), dest1)
    elif (f.endswith("sow.out")):
        shutil.move(os.path.join(source, f), dest2)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work; let me know if it doesn't:

```
import os
import shutil

srcdir = r'G:\Tables\\'
destdir = r'G:\Tables\Soil'

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)

    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
        dataname = f.name

    print dataname

    shutil.move(fullpath, dest)
```

Comment: Thank you Cyphase. Still something further seems to be wrong: I get  
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'G:\\Tables\\\\Soil'    
 at line 13:     with open(filepath, 'r') as f:

Comment: @M.Jimenez, sounds like you don't have read access to that file :).